# How does ObjectOutputStream call writeObject when the object is very large?

Tags: sockets, objectoutputstream, large-data

I have a large file that needs to be transferred over socket from server to client. If I want to use `writeObject` in `ObjectOutputStream` to send the object, what's the normal way to do it? How about reading at the client side?

Comment: You will call ObjectInputStream.readObject () in client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073024/receive-an-object-over-tcp-ip

Comment: If you want to use `writeObject()`, you use `writeObject()`. What's the question?

Comment: My question is how the large data is wrapped into a object that can be transferred by writeObject(). In other words, do I need to break the data into different segments and then wrap them separately into objects?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with Object Streams, they have the bad side effect to store and keep the Objects in memory to prevent double instances. Close it as soon as you are done with it.

If the object is large, you can chain your stream with a compressor, there are many good compression Objects in java like `DeflatorOutputStream` and `InflatorInputStream`.

For a quick tutorial on how to do it, check this :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, whatever it is.

Comment: He didn't ask about (a) appropriateness/pitfalls of using object streams or (b) compression. That merely leaves your link, which makes the relevant parts of this a link-only answer.

Answer (score -1):

> do I need to break the data into different segments ... ?

No. Just call `writeObject()` at one end and `readObject()` at the other. TCP will sort out all the segmentation for you.