# Get Object instancied by other class in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, object

I have a problem with it: In main class I created a object

`District d = new District(district, sequence);`

This main class create another thread.

This thread when access the instance of the object can't do it, only if the variables are static, because if not, appear this message : non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context.

My problem is: I can't use static fields, and I have a infinite loop in Main class, ie I can't use get method too.

How to access the object created in main class? Or, in another hand, why I can't access the arguments using non-static fields?

Please, consider any solution outside this as possible, even creating new class/methods/variables.

```
Output output = new Output(client);
        Thread to = new Thread(output);
        to.start();

        ++i;
    }

    while(true){

        for(i = 0; i < neighborhood.size(); ++i){
            //rand.nextInt((max+1) - min) + min;
            Edge edge = new Edge(id, neighborhood.get(i), 
                    rand.nextInt((10 + 1) - 1) + 1);
            district.add(edge);
        }

        District d = new District(district, sequence);

        ++sequence;

        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

And the thread:

```
public class Output implements Runnable {

private Socket client;

// Construtor do metódo
Output(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    // Obtendo os objetos de controle do fluxo de comunicação
   ObjectOutputStream output = null;
   try {
       output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Input.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }

   while(true){
       District district = new District(District.district, District.sequence);
        try {
            output.writeUnshared(district);
            System.out.println("Objeto enviado");
            output.flush();
            output.reset();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Output.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Output.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry you got some many downvotes without any explanation.  But it's probably because you have not posted the code you are having trouble with.  Having actual code to examine is very important.  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some helpful tips on how to post code in a way that will get you better help. Good luck.

Comment: You're almost there.  Can you make sure to at least post the entire class and method?  For instance, in your 2nd block, it's not clear to me if that's the `run` method of a `Runnable` or `Thread` or something else.  I'll be checking.

Comment: And please specify which line exactly is the one you are having trouble with.

Comment: Yeap, this class implements Runnable. I add full code of class.

Comment: My problem is here `District district = new District(District.district, District.sequence);`

Comment: Ok, so as I see it, looks like you are trying to access variables called `district` and `sequence`.  But I can't see where those are defined.  Can you provide that context as well please?

Comment: The variable is defined on Main class, and used by class for create a new object here: `District d = new District(district, sequence);`

Comment: I have to see it in code.  Please post your main class in its entirety as well.  Also, I have to say, that it is very unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish in the main and in the separate thread?  Without a clear explanation of your objective, I will probably be able to give you an immediate fix for your question, but it doesn't mean that your program will work as intended or be designed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the District as an argument to the Output constructor?

```
public class Output implements Runnable {

private Socket client;
private District district;

Output(Socket client, District district) {
    this.client = client;
    this.district = district;
}
```

Comment: Oh! I very embarassed...It is a good alternative and I not think about this before. But, if I have multiple objects in different types, sending via the same output,  and it's work? I need send another object too for the same client.

In another discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910350/how-to-send-an-object-over-tcp-in-java

The guy cite module between client/server, and this make sense too me, because I send the same object for many clients, and this clients work with server too for anothers.

Comment: And, if I created the Output Class one time with the socket client, I suppose is not necessarily created each time that I need the new object to send...